# ESLint with TypeScript, how to disable the strict null check?

Tags: typescript, eslint

ESLint is complaining that my object might be null even though there is an if statement around it.

```
     const user: User | null = getUser()

      if (user) { //  if (user !== null) doesn't work either
        await user.updateProfile({
          displayName: this.displayName
        })
      }
```

Sometimes it doesn't show this error and sometimes it does and it's impossible to get rid of. So I just want this rule disabled altogether but I can't find the rule name.

What rule name in ESLint is this or how else can I turn this off?

Comment: What is the exact linter error message? And a reproducible sample would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
const user: User | null = getUser()

      if (user instanceof User) { //  if (user !== null) doesn't work either
        await user.updateProfile({
          displayName: this.displayName
        })
      }
```